# Can you identify the set that these bird-like LEGO assemblies came out of?

Tags: set-identification

I would like to find out what set these pieces belong to.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial #70003 LEGO Legends of Chima Eris' Eagle Interceptor released in 2013:   https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70003-1#T=S&O=